# Fstab cache seems funky, filling up

Tags: linux, s3fs

We have an Amazon Server with an S3 mounted partition.  I like to think the mount is working, but the directory specified under the use_cache directive is filling up very rapidly, and is not shrinking back down, is this normal?

The config in fstab is `s3fs#filemanager /home/user/mounts/FileManager fuse user,use_cache=/home/user/tmp,allow_other,uid=NN,gid=NNN 0 0`

Both the mounted directory and the cache are growing at the same rate.  Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: not quite related to your question, but take a look at RioFS: https://github.com/skoobe/riofs, this is an alternative to s3fs application. RioFS allows you to set cache limits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation:

If enabled via "use_cache" option, s3fs automatically maintains a local cache of files in the folder specified by use_cache. Whenever s3fs needs to read or write a file on s3 it first downloads the entire file locally to the folder specified by use_cache and operates on it. When fuse release() is called, s3fs will re-upload the file to s3 if it has been changed.

The folder specified by use_cache is just a local cache. It can be deleted at any time. s3fs re-builds it on demand. Note: this directory grows unbounded and can fill up a file system dependent upon the bucket and reads to that bucket. Take precaution by using a quota system or routinely clearing the cache (or some other method).